# How to find node js location in mac M1?

Tags: node.js

I want to remove node to install it with nvm but I can't uninstall it.
I installed node twice, once I installed it wrong and the second time I did it right, I uninstalled one of the two nodes but the second time I don't know where it is and because of that I can't uninstall it.

I already try:

- brew uninstall --force node
- look tutorial how to uninstall node js from mac M1

Does anyone know how to find node location on mac M1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this location:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node
```

And maybe this post will be useful:
[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)